# Android: Connection timeout on device while connecting to the server on localhost

Tags: java, php, android, http, android-networking

I could not figure out why this is happening. I'm using PHP server and posting data from Android application to the server. When I'm using emulator all things are working fine but when I'm using my Android device for testing I'm getting Connection Timeout error. I'm using the same same network on which my server is on android device. I'm pasting my console log here so that, you can get a clear idea regarding this:

```
10-15 12:09:25.593: W/System.err(24334): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.0.2.2:80 timed out
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:156)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at com.example.insertuserdetails.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:78)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 12:09:25.609: W/System.err(24334):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-15 12:09:25.617: W/System.err(24334):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
10-15 12:09:25.617: W/System.err(24334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 12:09:25.617: W/System.err(24334):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-15 12:09:25.617: W/System.err(24334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
10-15 12:09:25.617: W/System.err(24334):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
10-15 12:09:25.617: W/System.err(24334):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my JSON code :

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/insert_user_details.php";
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpParams params = client.getParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 15000);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setHeader("json", jsonObject.toString());
                StringEntity se = null;
                se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                        "application/json"));
                httpPost.setEntity(se);
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
                int i = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Status: " + i,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Please help me overcoming this weird situation.

Comment: you can increase connection time..
have you tried that,.??

Comment: are you trying to connect to your local server???

Comment: @SilentKiller No, I have not tried that. How to do that?

Comment: @manindersingh Ya local server, I have updated my code, please see!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you should see that how to open local host on your android device.
Because on your android device you can't access your local host normally.

Comment: Can you give some idea about this or any useful link, I'll try that out!

Comment: you can search SO for this, one of the link to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device

Answer (score 0):

try to increase Connection timeout...

```
HttpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection  + 10000 );
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
```

**Your Code :**

```
                String url = "http://10.0.2.2/insert_user_details.php";
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 15000);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            httpPost.setHeader("json", jsonObject.toString());
            StringEntity se = null;
            se = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
            httpPost.setEntity(se);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            int i = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Status: " + i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Tried your code. No progress, I''m getting still the same error.

Comment: have you connected with same network or can you connect with same network with wifi..??